# Realm not fully saved

Tags: android, realm

Is realm have something like listener for committing data?

My code is

```
...  
RealmDatabase.submitNewUser(mainActivity.getMyRealm(), userModel);
mainActivity.closeKeyboard();
mainActivity.onBackPressed();
...

public static void submitNewUser(Realm myRealm, UserModel user) {
    myRealm.beginTransaction();
    UserDb userDb = myRealm.createObject(UserDb.class);
    userDb.setUserid(getNextUserId(myRealm));
    userDb.setName(user.name);
    ....
    myRealm.commitTransaction();
}

private static int getNextUserId(Realm myRealm) {
    try {
        return myRealm.where(UserDb.class).max("userid").intValue() + 1;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

After saving the data, I closed fragment and back to previous fragment.

On start function, checking if have data

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (loading.isShowing()) loading.dismiss();
    if (reloadList && checkContent()) {
        ....
    }
    reloadList = true;
}

private boolean checkContent() {
    users = RealmDatabase.loadUserList(mainActivity.getMyRealm());
    if (users.size() > 0 && users.get(0).userid > 0) {
        // note:
        // user id is auto increment while saved
        // if no data, return dataset with userid = 0 for other purpose
        return true;
    } else {
        ....
        return false;
    }
}

public static List<UserModel> loadUserList(Realm myRealm) {
    List<UserModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    RealmResults<UserDb> results = myRealm.where(UserDb.class).findAll();
    results = results.sort("userid", Sort.DESCENDING);

    for (UserDb result : results) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.userid = result.getUserid();
        ....
        userModel.note = result.getNote();
        list.add(userModel);
    }
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.userid = 0;
        userModel.note = "You still have no user at this time";
        list.add(userModel);
    }
    return list;
}
```

`checkContent()`, `user.size` detected as 1 (new data is added) but userid still 0.

Am I missing something in this logic? Because everything is working well if I reopen app after I add a new user.

**Update**

After using listener, I got my dataset but still not showing my content. After some trial, I found that my list view is not showing  the data even after I re-input data and do notifydataset on adapter.

```
users = RealmDatabase.loadUserList(mainActivity.getMyRealm());
homeAdapter.reloadList(users);

....

public void reloadList(List<UserModel> users) {
    this.users = users;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Update #2**

Everything is going well for the 2nd, 3rd, and later item except the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @epicPandaForce answer, i use listener to my code.
and to solved my problem as i mentioned in the last comment in @epicPandaForce answer, i change my code like this

```
getMyRealm().addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Realm>() {
     @Override
     public void onChange(Realm element) {
           // previous code in my activity
           // getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

           // new code in my activity
           fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
     }
 });
```

those code not really inside the listener instead calling function on my activity. those placement just for where its called.

Answer (score 0):

> is realm have something like listener for commiting data?

Yes

```
realmResults.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

One must keep a field reference to the RealmResults.

> everything is working well if i reopen app after add new user.

Probably the ArrayList you build from the RealmResults is not updated.

Comment: i will try that changelistener later. about ArrayList not updated, i had notice this then i add users = RealmDatabase.loadUserList(mainActivity.getMyRealm()); on checkContent but still not working

Comment: Calling `realm.beginTransaction()` updates the version of the Realm, so it's impossible to read outdated data from Realm after a UI thread write transaction, AFAIK

Comment: isn't it called first before add and update data? and then called commitTransaction() after that.

Comment: Well `beginTransaction` makes Realm be updated to its latest version, and `commitTransaction` will commit the new version, and that is when RealmChangeListeners are called if the commit is synchronous on UI thread.

Comment: thanks for explanation. things that funny in my code is only bugged at the first item. and to show that first item in my list is open another fragment and back again. as alternate solution, i want to try change the flow a bit.